# VS2013 Cant Install almost anything through NUget (specially requiring entityframework)

Tags: nuget

I can't install Entity Framework via Nuget on Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

I've tried:

- reinstalling it
- update it (vs2013) patch5
- .net frameworks fixer (FixDotNet2017.cab)
- other nugets versions
- EFTools6.1.3ForVS2013.msi
- msxml6_SDK.msi
- repairing w/ MSXML
- dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe

I've wasted a whole week on this - but in the same PC another VS 2017 works fine..

Here are the outputs:

```
ENTITYFRAMEWORK Install failed. Rolling back...

Installing 'EntityFramework 6.1.3'.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.1.3'.
Adding 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' to WebApplication5.
Uninstalling 'EntityFramework 6.1.3'.
Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 6.1.3'.
*Install failed. Rolling back...*
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'EntityFramework'.
At line:1 char:17
+  Install-Package <<<<  EntityFramework
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

What I really need to DO is add a new item to my solution , an ADO.NET ENTITY DATA MODEL

and the error follows like:
*library not registered Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))*

Comment: Please edit your question and format it to help other readers to understand your problem. Putting things in **bold** won't help much.

Comment: I've edited it to be more readable.